# How to change C drive from logical partition to primary

Tags: windows, partitioning

I've looked everywhere for an answer to this question and can't find one anywhere, so hopefully this will help others in the future.

I have shrunk my C drive in order to make a partition to install windows 10 on.

In doing so I changed my C drive from primary to logical, it still functions perfectly and I have no issues. I am yet to install windows 10 but was wondering if it is okay to delete the windows 10 partition created (see screenshot), change the c drive back to primary and then install to unallocated space?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the new partition you created (in this case labeled Windows 10), will change the drive to unallocated, and if you join it with the C partition, will change the drive to dynamic and making the booting impossible. If you want to delete the Windows 10 partition (where later you can install windows 10), go on and do so (if you have nothing on that partition). Later you can convert the C: partition back to primary.
Use a free tool, like [Partition Master](http://www.partition-tool.com/). You can convert the drive from logical back to primary, and after applying your computer will restart to complete the operation. 
To make it simple for you, I'm writing it in simple short steps:

1. Delete "Windows 10" Partition
2. Change the 'C:' partition to primary with Partition Master (windows will restart to complete the operation)
3. Install Windows 10 on the unallocated partition.

Please let me know if you need more help.